# Fastapi app: empty array or TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Tags: python, backend, fastapi, sqlmodel

So, Im doing simple todo-api app with fastapi and sqlmodel. Migrations went fine, but if I run my server, I dont see anything except empy array. I added some data in db file with DB Browser for SQLite, so it isn't empty.
And when I run my server and go to "/", I see only empty array and no data, and if I go to "/1/", I see this:
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

My main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn
from endpoints.routers import router
from database.db import engine
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router)

# def create_db_and_tables():
#     SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host='localhost', port=8000, reload=True)
    # create_db_and_tables()
```

routers.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from models.todo import ToDo
from repos.todo_repo import select_all_todos, select_todo
from database.db import session
from sqlmodel import Session, select

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/", tags=['Todos'])
def show_todos():
    todos = select_all_todos()
    return todos


@router.get('/{id}/', response_model=ToDo, tags=['Todos'])
def select_one(id: int):
    todo_found = select_todo(id)
    return todo_found
```

repos:

```
from models.todo import ToDo
from sqlmodel import Session, select, or_

def select_all_todos():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        todos = select(ToDo)
        results = session.exec(todos)
        todo = results.all()
        return todo
    
def select_todo(id):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(ToDo)
        statement = statement.where(ToDo.id==id)
        if not statement:
            return "Error"
        result = session.exec(statement)
        return result.first()
```

models:

```
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel


class ToDo(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    is_done: bool = False
```

database.py file:

```
from sqlmodel import create_engine, Session

eng = 'database.db'

sqlite_url = f'sqlite:///{eng}'
engine = create_engine(sqlite_url, echo=True)
session = Session(bind=engine)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 231, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 162, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/concurrency.py", line 41, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/to_thread.py", line 31, in run_sync
    return await get_asynclib().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 937, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 867, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/endpoints/routers.py", line 17, in select_one
    todo_found = select_todo(id)
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/repos/todo_repo.py", line 16, in select_todo
    if not statement:
  File "/home/aleksandr/Programming/Sites/myTodo/backend/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 590, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Boolean value of this clause is not defined")
TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

Comment: I think it would be useful if you attach a traceback here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the exception is that you're not actually executing the statement in `select_todo` before checking for error. In SqlModel statement is a special kind of object to build and process a query, so it can't be directly checked for boolean value.

If you want to check if there are any results, place this statement under `exec` and check `results` instead.

There's no sense to check the statement itself in if, it's constructed successfully if no exception raised by that point

Answer (score 1):

From reading the Traceback, I'd say that whatever type `statement.where(ToDo.id==id)` returns, seems not to have a `__bool__()` Magic Method defined. So you can't check for "truthy-ness" in the `if` statement.